# Display Date Label in axes - chart js/ng2 charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

[image: Snapshot of the x axes label]

Need to display labels date in the x axes in the interval . Data should remain same only date interval shoould be displayed as per the snapshot.

For simple numbers on y axes able to achieve this using "ticks"

```
            max: 5000,
            min: 0,
            stepSize:4000
```

But in case of date not sure the property which is to be used. 
Attached the code snippet [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example-5xxqc9?file=app/app.component.ts) url

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to show months instead of days for the axis labels. You can achieve this by changing the `unit` property:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'month'
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this unit property but that is changing graphs as well. I want graphs to be displayed in days . Only label should be month wise so that there is no clustering/congesstion on x axes. Refer the updated code in stackblitz. (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example-ldmsyi?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I'm not familiar with stackblitz, but neither of the examples you link to create a chart that looks like your screenshot. They both create a default line chart, not a bar chart.

Comment: I have created simple bar chart only. Stackblitz is just like jsfiddle. You can see the code there. If I remove following piece of code , it will look like just my screenshot:  options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'month'
            }
        }]
    }
}

Comment: Check this url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example-d2ymfn?file=app/app.component.ts. You will see the same bar graph as in snapshot

Comment: It looks like stackblitz doesn't work with Firefox (there are lots of 'SecurityErrors' in the console).  Look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epmr4w9f/13/) to see two charts that differ only in the time axis unit. There is no difference in the presented data, only how the axis is drawn.